# How do I access a polymer core-style producer element to set its fields?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm creating a polymer element that will change its background image url every now and then to one fetched with a jsonp call.  I'm using a core-style element with an id attribute (and therefore a producer) that's outside my element, and another one with a ref attribute inside my element's template, which consumes the producer.  I have a bound model reference inside the css code of the producer that I want to change every so often to reflect the new image url. My issue is that I'm having trouble finding the correct property of the correct object into which to put the url so that it will push an update of the css code inside the producer.

Here's the code.  I've removed the ajax call in order to keep it short and simple:

```
<core-style id="my-style">
  .main {
    background-image: url({{ someUrlField }});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
</core-style>

<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <core-style ref="my-style"></core-style>
    <div class="main">
      Some content.
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
      ready: function() {
        var awesomeImageUrl = 'http://whatever.com/radness.jpg';
        // where do I put it?
        // document.getElementById('my-style') returns null, as does
        // document._currentScript.ownerDocument.getElementById('my-style')
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I've tried locating the element with a standard document.getElementById call, but it comes up empty.  I've also tried the document._currentScript.ownerDocument.getElementById shown on the [Polymer docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-style), but that also returns a null for me. The only way around this that I've found is to use the CoreStyle.g global object, which does cause the update I want, but that feels like pollution.

Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: It's not 100% clear from the docs, but I believe `document._currentScript.ownerDocument.getElementById('my-style')` needs to live outside of your `<polymer-element>`. Have you tried putting it in a `<script>` just below the polymer-element definition?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That retrieves a reference to the correct object, though it seems to have the unfortunate side effect of placing my assignment statement outside the scope of "my-element," which is where my ajax callbacks live.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element using the list map from the global CoreStyle object with `CoreStyle.list["my-style"]` (Ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-style.html).

### Example

```
<link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/core-style/core-style.html">

<core-style id="demo-changeCoreStyle-Style">
 :host {
     background-image: url({{ someUrlField }});
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     display: block;
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
  }
</core-style>
<polymer-element name="demo-changeCoreStyle" >
 <template>
  <core-style ref="demo-changeCoreStyle-Style"></core-style>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    There is some content here<br>
    and here<br>
    and even here
 </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        CoreStyle.list["demo-changeCoreStyle-Style"].someUrlField = 'http://www.gnu.org/graphics/gnu-head-30-years-anniversary.png';
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```